# How can I build a contingency table with a range of values for the first factor?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python and I wanto to create a contingency table like this:
[image]

I learned that using this code I can group the whole dataset as I need

```
data_group = data.groupby(pd.cut(data['review_scores_rating'], (20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))).sum()
```

I already know how to create the contingency table using the following code:

```
tabla_contingencia = pd.crosstab(data['review_scores_rating'], data['room_types'], margins = True)
```

However, I havent' managed yet to build the contingency table with the range of values of the first factor. How could I do it?

Thanks!